# Is there a directory of freely available pro-vegan leaflets and literature?

Tags: outreach, resources

I'm hoping to hand out some leaflets about animal agriculture at an upcoming event, and I'm wondering if there is a collection of premade resources like posters and leaflets. Ideally everything would be available to print freely with a Creative Commons license.

I'm not looking for links to specific organizations that offer leaflets, but rather a directory that offers a variety of content in both style and tone.

Comment: It does not seem to be the case. That said, it would be really difficult to answer "no" to this question without the risk of the answer being wrong or outdated. Directories on the internet are difficult to maintain; [search](https://www.ecosia.org) [engines](https://www.duckduckgo.com) are an excellent tool to find vegan outreach material.

Answer (score 2):

There are many social media groups interested in vegan media and content for activism. The best collective I have found would probably be the subreddit called [r/veganactivism](https://www.reddit.com/r/VeganActivism/). [Here](https://veganactivism.org/pages/reddit-activism) is a partner website that discusses the use of the subreddit

On the website there is the following claim:

> … the most comprehensive verified list of Vegan Activism organizations online for Vegans looking to jump into activism. Whether you have a lot of time or little, whether you're new or experienced, there's an organization here that's looking for your help to spread our compassionate vegan message.

The subreddit and associated website don't necessarily accommodate your request for generalised material, but they are a start. You can direct a request to them if you need better content. Or, post to the subreddit asking for alternative material. Maybe even ask for volunteers willing to produce content.

Another option is the poorly tended Wikipedia list for [vegan media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vegan_media). It doesn't offer a lot for activists, but it is an intended repository to identify information sources.

Answer (score 0):

**Farm Sanctuary**

- V-lish Plant-Based Recipe Guide
- African American Vegan Starter Guide
- Factory Farming and the Environment
- Factory Farming
- How We Treat the Animals We Eat
- The Truth Behind Beef
- The Truth Behind Dairy
- The Truth Behind Poultry
- The Truth Behind Pork
- The Truth Behind Eggs
- The Truth Behind Humane Meat, Milk and Eggs

https://www.farmsanctuary.org/learn/educational-literature

**United Poltry Concerns**

- Chickens
- Turkeys
- Pavos
- "Free-Range" Poultry and Eggs: Not All They're Cracked Up to Be
- A Wing & A Prayer: The Kapparot Chicken-Swinging Ritual
- How I Learned the Truth About Eggs
- Peeper: A Story of Unending Love
- Birds Suffer Horribly for Pillows & Coats
- The Truth About Feather Hair Extensions
- Factory Farming vs. Alternative Farming:The Humane Hoax
- Instead of Chicken, Turkey, and Eggs: Commercially Available Vegan Alternatives
- Ostriches and Emus: Nowhere to Hide
- [Don't Plants Have Feelings Too?](https://www.upc-online.org/activism/dont_plants_have_feelings.pdf)
- Viva, the Chicken Hen/Chickens Raised for Meat
- Jane – one tiny chicken foot...
- The Life of One Battery Hen
- Poultry Slaughter: The Need for Legislation
- Intensive Poultry Production: Fouling the Environment
- Damn Dairy

https://www.upc-online.org/merchandise/handout.html

Search page ^ for PDF.

**The Vegan Society**

- Vegan for the environment
- Why vegan?
- Vegan for the animals
- Vegan 101
- Plant power
- Plant based nutrition
- VeGuide (free app as a guide through 30 days of plant-based living)
- Vegan prisoners booklet

https://www.vegansociety.com/resources/publications-and-video/leaflets

**Vegan Outreach**

Various lil' booklets; here are a few:

- Compassionate Athlete and Guide to Cruelty-Free Eating
- ¿Qué es el especismo?
- Australian
- Bulgarian
- Indian/Hindi
- Environmentalists (audience)

https://veganoutreach.org/booklet-pdfs

## Bonus - posters

**Free from Harm**

http://www.postersagainstcruelty.com/free-from-harm.html

**Humane Facts**

http://www.postersagainstcruelty.com/humane-facts.html

**Mercy for Animals**

http://www.postersagainstcruelty.com/mercy-for-animals.html

**The Humane League**

http://www.postersagainstcruelty.com/thl-posters.html

**Vegan Outreach**

http://www.postersagainstcruelty.com/vegan-outreach.html